# Azure, API Authentication, allow anonymous for 1 operation

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET web app and secured by AD authentication.

[image]

If I don't pass valid auth token, I get this error which is expected.

[image]

I have 5 operation in my API and all are now secure but for one of the operations, I want to enable anonymous access. For example I don't want to secure a specific highlighted endpoint, is it possible?

[image]

I have added "[AllowAnonymous]" but I still get error.

Comment: Are you validating the bearer token anywhere in your code?

Comment: No, not validating anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using Azure's built-in authentication for web apps (Easy Auth).

Based on the documentation, it is not possible to mix authenticated and unauthenticated endpoints using this. You could choose to have all endpoints require authentication (which is what you have configured currently) or have all endpoints do not require authentication (from Easy Auth point of view) and handle the authentication in your code.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authorization-behavior):

[image]

You would need to write a custom filter that will intercept the requests and handle authentication there.

For example, this is how we are handling it in our code. We wrote a custom filter that would validate the incoming token. It would also skip the validation if an endpoint allows anonymous access.

```
public class BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeFilter
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Handle endpoints that have [AllowAnonymous] set
        if (context.Filters.Any(item => item is IAllowAnonymousFilter))
        {
            return;
        }
        // handle endpoints that require authentication
    }
}
```

This is how we are wiring it up in `Startup.cs` class:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter));
});
```